# Graph of .NET exceptions thrown per second?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, perfmon

I want to monitor the number of .NET exceptions thrown per second.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The .NET runtime publishes performance monitor metrics on the number of exceptions thrown per second. Check it out:

[image]